# Group BY Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

First im mysql noob :D
Ive tried searching but nothing that can help.
Im trying to update my database with this query.

```
UPDATE client SET cntr_limit=(SELECT fulltraffic from 
(SELECT
    client.id,
    (SUM(ipacct.byteso)+SUM(ipacct.bytesi)) as fulltraffic
        FROM client 
            LEFT JOIN ips ON client.id = ips.cid
            LEFT JOIN ipacct ON ips.ip = ipacct.target
            WHERE ipacct.tag = 1
        GROUP BY client.id
     ) as x
) +322122547200 ;
```

Im getting Subquery returns more than 1 row. 
I know the subquery cant have more than one row but i need to work with GROUP BY. If i remove GROUP BY query works but every client get the traffic calculated from all the ips,
instead of traffic calculated differently for every id.

If i use.

```
 SELECT
    client.id,
    (SUM(ipacct.byteso)+SUM(ipacct.bytesi)) as fulltraffic
        FROM client 
            LEFT JOIN ips ON client.id = ips.cid
            LEFT JOIN ipacct ON ips.ip = ipacct.target
            WHERE ipacct.tag = 1
        GROUP BY client.id;
```

im getting

```
id  fulltraffic
1   5100993724986
3   410550845834
4   790726628007
5   204212941099
6   440290245087
8   587044969960
```

if i remove GROUP BY im getting

```
id  fulltraffic
1   487196626849368
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the table schema please? As well as some sample data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IN` instead of `=`.

```
UPDATE client SET cntr_limit IN (SELECT....
```

and remove the last alias `+322122547200 ;`

but a better way to do it is to join the tables on `UPDATE` statement,

```
UPDATE  client a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  client.id,
                    (SUM(ipacct.byteso)+SUM(ipacct.bytesi)) as fulltraffic
            FROM    client 
                    LEFT JOIN ips 
                        ON client.id = ips.cid
                    LEFT JOIN ipacct ON ips.ip = ipacct.target
            WHERE   ipacct.tag = 1
            GROUP   BY client.id
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
SET     a.cntr_limit = b.fulltraffic
```

Comment: i have one more question, what is `+322122547200`?

Comment: its adding +300 Gigabytes traffic to already calculated traffic.

Comment: so the `UPDATE` statement should be `SET     a.cntr_limit = b.fulltraffic + 322122547200`

Answer (score 0):

> If i remove GROUP BY query works but every client get the traffic calculated from all the ips, instead of traffic calculated differently for every id.

Yes and this is exactly what you want. What you're missing, if you want only one row, is a where clause that specifies a client.id

If all you are trying to do is update `cntr_limit` to be the fulltraffic + 322122547200 for all clients, your query is fine and will update all clients at once with their respective totals.

If you are processing one client at a time, you need to filter by client.id

Answer (score 0):

How about a join update with a correlated subquery:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1a9a/2)

```
UPDATE client c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT a.id as id,
 (SUM(ipact.byteso) + SUM(ipact.bytesi)) as ft
 FROM client a
 LEFT JOIN ips ON a.id = ips.cid
 LEFT JOIN ipact ON ips.id = ipact.ipp
            WHERE ipact.tag = 1
        GROUP BY a.id
     ) x
on c.id = x.id
SET c.climit = x.ft
;
```

Comment: I believe you are adding `322122547200` value to each of the new value you are setting up to the `cntr_limit`.. :)